# How to add fluent validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have 2 properties

1. VacancyId (string)
2. CompanyId (int)

I am trying to make both required and check if there is any value in any one of them.

```
RuleFor(x => x.CompanyId).NotNull().DependentRules(() => { RuleFor(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.VacancyId)); }).WithMessage("Invalid request");
```

Comment: "I want" is not a valid problem description. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: edited code in my question

Comment: @ShivangGupta, you want to make both of your properties required right?

Comment: @Dimirti only one of them is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RuleFor(x => x.CompanyId).NotNull().WithMessage("Invalid request").When(x=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.VacancyId));
```

https://fluentvalidation.net/start#collections

Comment: You said you are trying to validate CompanyId but in code you are validating CampaignId!